# Store MotionEvent values in an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, canvas, view, motionevent

Greetings one and all,

So I am using onDraw in a custom View class to draw shapes on a RelativeLayout + TableLayout, all that works fine.

Inside the `MotionEvent`'s `ACTION_MOVE` I pass the `X & Y` to my CustomView and call a method that returns a unique ID value for each set of coordinates / shape respectively.

Due to dragging my finger from one Shape to another: multiple values will be returned to the Console as expected and I would like to store these values in an `Array`for future use. The issue I am having is that when I try to store the values, it only stores one value in a case where the console shows 4.

Console output looks like:

> 06-22 07:28:56.173 zar.myapp I/System.out: value: 354
>
> 06-22 07:28:56.193 zar.myapp I/System.out: value: 858
>
> 06-22 07:28:56.213 zar.myapp I/System.out: value: 989
>
> 06-22 07:28:56.213 zar.myapp I/System.out: value: 789

Code:

```
ArrayList XYcoords  = new ArrayList();

switch (event.getAction()) {
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
   
 return true;
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

  ///Single value for each finger movement.
   DotView endView = getChildForTouch((TableLayout) v, x, y); 

   XYcoords.add(endView.getId() );

 break;

 case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    ///I tried adding them from here as well.

 ///When I check the size of `XYcoords` it allways return 1
 System.out.println("Array Size: " + XYcoords.size());

 break;
```

**DotView class:** in my `MainActivity` where I construct my table grid I call: `Dotview.setId(i);` to assign a unique ID to each cell (verified). (I only shared the relevant codes):

```
private static class DotView extends View {

        private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 100;
        private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
        private Rect mBorderRect = new Rect();
        private Paint mCirclePaint = new Paint();
        private int mRadius = DEFAULT_SIZE / 4;
        int id;

        public DotView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);
            mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            mCirclePaint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#0099cc"));
            mBorderRect.left = 0;
            mBorderRect.top = 0;
            mBorderRect.right = getMeasuredWidth();
            mBorderRect.bottom = getMeasuredHeight();
            canvas.drawRect(mBorderRect, mPaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(getMeasuredWidth() / 2, getMeasuredHeight() / 2,
                    mRadius, mCirclePaint);
        }

        
        public void setId(Int id){
            this.id = id;
        }
        public int getId()
        {
            return this.id;
        }

    }
```

**getChildForTouch**

```
private DotView getChildForTouch(TableLayout table, float x, float y) {
                    final int childWidth = ((TableRow) table.getChildAt(0))
                            .getChildAt(0).getWidth();
                    final int childHeight = ((TableRow) table.getChildAt(0))
                            .getChildAt(0).getHeight();


                    // find out the row of the child
                    int row = 0;
                    do {
                        if (y > childHeight) {
                            row++;
                            y -= childHeight;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    } while (y > childHeight);
                    int column = 0;
                    do {
                        if (x > childWidth) {
                            column++;
                            x -= childWidth;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    } while (x > childWidth);
                    return (DotView) ((TableRow) table.getChildAt(row))
                            .getChildAt(column);
                }
```

More code can be supplied on request.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ```endView.getId()``` will return the view ID or is the method that generates that value ? If it's the method that computes that single value, make sure that it returns different values. (logg it before adding it to the array)

Comment: The custom method `endView.getId()` uses the X and Y to get the unique ID  I assigned to each shape drawn on the canvas. And yes, it returns different values; See the output I have above.

Comment: The one value contained in the array, is it one that you've generated (is it printed in console) ?

Comment: yes sir, I think it's always the last one: 789 (In this example) - but I am not sure. I was thinking maybe I could try and store the raw `X + Y` coords to an Array, and then do a `for` loop and pass the stored X + Y to my custom view class? idk

Comment: Could you share your `DotView` class?

Comment: just for debug, try to store the string value of the resulting int...I'm just curious, will it work.

Comment: @antonio post updated. @danypata -  are you saying convert each unique `ID` to string and try to store them like that ? will do in a few mins to see.

Comment: Yes, I'm just curious if it will work with String value.

Comment: Can you also share the relevant parts of `getChildForTouch`?

Comment: @antonio Question updated. @danypata - I did this in the `ACTION_MOVE` `XYcoords.add(String.valueOf(endView.getId()));` and the array size is still 1.

Comment: Here's something very interesting which might solve this issue: if I do this in `the ACTION_MOVE:` `System.out.println("ID: " + XYcoords.get(0));` and then drag my fingers from Point A - B it outputs each point's ID successfully..It`s like all the ID's are being stored in the first index (0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue I am having is that when I try to store the values, it only
>   stores one value in a case where the console shows 4

I'm assuming you're creating the XYcoords list inside the onTouch() callback, in which case it will have a size of 1 corresponding to the current touch event. As the user moves his finger onTouch() will be called again with another touch event, at this point you'll create a **new** XYcoords list with one entry and so on...

To solve this, move the XYcoords list initialization **outside** of the onTouch() callback, like a field in the class. This way you'll not recreate it every time a touch event happens.

As a side note, I'm assuming that with your current code you're trying to store in a list the DotViews the user has touched as he moved his finger. In this case you'll most likely not want to simply do XYcoords.add(endView.getId()) in MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE as you'll end up with hundreds of duplicate entries(as there will be a lot of touch events that will be triggered inside a single DotView). Instead don't allow duplicates:

```
if (XYcoords.size() != 0) {
   // check to see if we aren't trying to add the same DotView reference
   // (meaning we are still inside the same DotView)
   int lastId = XYcoords.get(XYcoords.size() - 1);
   if (lastId != endView.getId()) {
      // not the same DotView so add it
      XYcoords.add(endView.getId());
   } 
} else {
   XYcoords.add(endView.getId()); // first event, must add it
}
```

In the case for MotionEvent.ACTION_UP you need to use(or store somewhere else the info in XYcoords) the data in XYcoords and **clear it** so next time the user starts touching the DotViews you have a fresh history(no items in XYcoords).